# Wordpress - How to use Ajax Load More plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I'm developing a website in wordpress and I want to load more news when scrolling but I already have a html structure and when I put ajax load more it put own structure and I don' want that.

I'm using the `Ajax Load More` plugin.

So, How can I use Ajax load more with this html structure:

```
<?php
          $posts = get_posts(['cat' => get_cat_ID("news")]);
                foreach($posts as $post){
                    setup_postdata($post);
            ?>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <a class="news-link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <div class="news">
              <div class="image">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') ?>
                <div class="mask">
                  <div class="icon">
                    <i class="icon-plus"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="title">
                <span>
                  <?php the_title(); ?>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div class="excerpt">
                <p class="date">
                  <?php echo get_the_date('Y-m-d'); ?>
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="excerpt">
                <p>
                  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <?php
                wp_reset_postdata();
            } ?>
```

If i put this shortcode it shows but not with the structure that i want.

```
[ajax_load_more id="7279302844" container_type="div" post_type="post" category="news"]
```

Thank you